# Getting author of transaction in pre-commit hook in SVN

Tags: svn, transactions, pre-commit-hook

I have a pre-commit hook script for SVN repository and I need to get the name of the author for every commit. According to SVN documentation, I can do this by using the command:

```
svnlook author -t [Transaction name] [Path to repository]
```

Whenever a commit is performed by a user, the repository path and the transaction name is passed as parameters to the script. But when I try to run the above command using that transaction name on the repository, I get an output "No such transaction". Why is this happening and how can I get the author name using the transaction name? I need it to perform some logging processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will need to be done in a *post*-commit hook. That transaction doesn't exist in the repository because this is a *pre*-commit hook. :)

Comment: So there is no way of telling who the author is in the pre-commit hook?

Comment: Ok, so I found out that I cannot get the author in the pre-commit hook, but that information can be obtained from the start-commit hook which will be called before pre-commit is called.